# Mail delivery failed: returning Email to sender

Tags: email, magento-1.9, email-delivery

I am Getting mail from Mail Delivery System.I attached the mail below.

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@test.com>
Date: Wed, Aug 9, 2017 at 10:00 PM
Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
To: info@test.com

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

test@gmail.com
    host alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [243.122.66.26]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:&lt;test@gmail.com&gt;:
    550-5.2.1 The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate that
    550-5.2.1 prevents additional messages from being delivered. For more
    550-5.2.1 information, please visit
    550 5.2.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ReceivingRatePerm p41si4843565qte.548 - gsmtp
Action: failed
Final-Recipient: test;test@gmail.com
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.2.1 The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate that
550-5.2.1 prevents additional messages from being delivered. For more
550-5.2.1 information, please visit
550 5.2.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ReceivingRatePerm p41si4843565qte.548 - gsmtp
```

I don't have any idea about this can anyone please help.

Comment: are you trying to send an email from info@test.com to test@gmail.com ? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't know about this email my client forward this mail. My problem is all the email sent from my client website are sent as spam mail. Can you Please guide to solve this problem